# Sum Column in Pandas Dataframe with condition on Other Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a pandas dataframe on this format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"i": [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                   "k": [2,3,1,3,4,5],
                   "Y_ik": [0,0,1,14,2,12]})
display(df)
```

```
    i   k   Y_ik
0   1   2   0
1   1   3   0
2   2   1   1
3   2   3   14
4   3   4   2
5   3   5   12
```

I want to, grouped by `(i,k)` which are unique, sum each `Y_ik` such that that for the current `(i,k)`, `k` does not appear in `(i,k)`. Result should look like:

```
    i   k   Y_ik new_column
0   1   2   0    28
1   1   3   0    14
2   2   1   1    28
3   2   3   14   15
4   3   4   2    13
5   3   5   12   3
```

An illustration of the problem:

```
(i,k)
(1,2): 0+14+2+12 = 28               
(1,3): 0+2+12 = 14          
(2,1): 0+14+2+12 = 28
(2,3): 1+2+12 = 15
(3,4): 0+1+12 = 13
(3,5): 0+1+2 = 3
```

Basically, I need to sum the `Y_ik` column on time per row with a condition based on `k` column. These sums should be in a new column of the dataframe. The method should be relatively fast since the dataframes in practice will be relatively large, so no `for loops` etc.

I tried

```
df.groupby(["i","k"]).apply(lambda x : (x[~x["k"].isin(df[["i","k"]])]["Y_ik"].sum()))
```

but this results in a column equal to `Y_ik`:

```
i  k
1  2     0
   3     0
2  1     1
   3    14
3  4     2
   5    12
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The solution proposed by @mozway works for the given example, but it produces `Nan` values for this extended problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"i": [1,1,2,2,3,3,8],
                   "k": [2,3,1,3,4,5,15],
                   "Y_ik": [0,0,1,14,2,12,1]})
display(df)
```

```
    i   k   Y_ik
0   1   2   0
1   1   3   0
2   2   1   1
3   2   3   14
4   3   4   2
5   3   5   12
6   8   15  1
```

```
s = df.groupby('k')['Y_ik'].sum()
df['new_column'] = df['i'].map(s).add(df['k'].map(s)).rsub(s.sum())
display(df)
```

```
    i   k   Y_ik    new_column
0   1   2   0       29.0
1   1   3   0       15.0
2   2   1   1       29.0
3   2   3   14      16.0
4   3   4   2       14.0
5   3   5   12      4.0
6   8   15  1       NaN
```

The new `df` contains a new row

```
    i   k   Y_ik
6   8   15  1
```

Comment: 1- "*no for loops*", but your example uses `apply`, which is based on a for loop. 2- why is (1, 2) `0+14+2+12` and not  `0+1+14+2+12`? The `1` is `(2, 1)`, so `k != k'`. Or, if you also want `k != i'`, then why keep the `14`?

Comment: @mozway 1- I tried to come up with a simple solution to illustrate the problem. What would a faster method than ```apply``` be?

2 - For ```(i,k) = (1,2)``` we have that ```k'=2```  from ```(1,2)``` and ```k'=1``` from ```(2,1)```, so sum all ```Y_ik``` but ```(1,2)``` and ```(2,1)```. In ```(i,k') = (2,3)```, ```3``` is not in ```(i,k) = (1,2)```, so keep ```Y_23=14``` in sum.

Comment: OK, so your description is misleading, you don't want to avoid `k == k'` but rather not `(i, k) == (i', k')` nor `(i, k) == (k', i')`?

Comment: Can you then explain the `(1, 3)`? I would expect `0+1+14+2+12` because no other row is `(1, 3)` or `(3, 1)`. Whatever your rule is, the logic is not consistent.

Comment: @mozway for ```(i,k) = (1,3)```, we check every row, that is, every pair of ```(i,k)```, say ```(i,k')```. If ```k'``` is either ```1``` or ```3```, then we skip that value in the sum. So for ```(i,k) = (1,3)``` we keep ```(i,k') = (1,2),(3,4),(3,5)``` since ```k' = 2,4,5``` is not in ```(1,3)```, and we skip ```(i,k')=(1,3),(2,1),(2,3)```.

Comment: OK, I got it, from the description I thought k/k' were the other way around

Comment: @mozway I understand that. I found it hard to explain the problem properly. Let me know if there is something more I can explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building from @mozway's solution, I modified his code a bit to give the correct outputs for your modified example. The issue with NaN's occur when there are values in `i` for which there are no matching `k`.
We resolve this rather simply by filling missing `i`-values with zero as follows:

```
si = dfX.groupby('i')['Y_ik'].sum()
sk = dfX.groupby('k')['Y_ik'].sum()

dfX['new_column'] = dfX['k'].map(si).fillna(0).add(dfX['k'].map(sk)).rsub(s)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   i   k  Y_ik  new_column
0  1   2     0        15.0
1  1   3     0         2.0
2  2   1     1        29.0
3  2   3    14         2.0
4  3   4     2        28.0
5  3   5    12        18.0
6  8  15     1        29.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorial solution would be to [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) on `k`, then map the value on i and k and subtract those from the total:

```
s = df.groupby('k')['Y_ik'].sum()

df['new_column'] = df['i'].map(s).add(df['k'].map(s)).rsub(s.sum())

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   i  k  Y_ik  new_column
0  1  2     0          28
1  1  3     0          14
2  2  1     1          28
3  2  3    14          15
4  3  4     2          13
5  3  5    12           3
```

Comment: Your solution looks good, but I tried it on a larger df and it ended up with a lot of ```Nan``` values in ```new_column```. I'm sure how I can illustrate it in the comments.

Comment: Please edit the question with an example that fails (reproducible, no missing data, and with the matching expected output).

Comment: I have added an example where it produces ```Nan``` value. What differs from other rows is that no value ```k'``` (but itself) exists such that ```k``` is not in ```(i,k)```. That is, it should be a sum of all the numbers on ```Y_ik``` column (but itself) axis.

Comment: It should be "... exists such that ```k'``` is not in ```(i,k)```". Can't edit comment.

Answer (score -2):

The issue with this    `df.groupby(["i","k"]).apply(lambda x : (x[~x["k"].isin(df["k"])]["Y_ik"].sum()))` is that when you use ***apply*** on the grouped DataFrame, the lambda function is applied to each group separately. However, the lambda function is using the whole DataFrame ***df*** to check for the condition ***~x["k"].isin(df["k"])***, which is not what you intended.

Use this to Calculate the sum of Y_ik for each (i, k) group    `grouped_sum = df.groupby(["i", "k"])["Y_ik"].sum().reset_index()`

Then calculate the new_column by summing Y_ik for the corresponding (i, k) group where k does not appear in (i, k)    `df["new_column"] = df.apply(lambda row: grouped_sum.loc[(grouped_sum["i"] == row["i"]) & (~grouped_sum["k"].isin(df[df["i"] == row["i"]]["k"])), "Y_ik"].sum(), axis=1)`

Lastly print the answer     `print(df)`